# rails 3.1.0 devise with cancan getting unauthorized with invalid username and/or password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I have a fairly simple app using devise and cancan for authentication and authorization. Everything works great except when users try signing in with invalid usernames and/or passwords. When this happens, we get an `error loading page` with the following exception in the logs:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-09 22:23:22 -0600
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"blahblahblahblah", "user"=>{"login"=>"asdasd", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (lower(username) = 'asdasd' OR lower(email) = 'asdasd') LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 74ms
```

I'm not sure what I need to set to allow the authorization and/or how to get more detailed logs to see exactly what is not authorized? If I enter valid credentials I can access the application and all other pieces of the app work as expected.

Comment: Did you finally find out what was going on?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been posted a couple months ago but I hot the same issue, and after fighting it for a few hours, overwriting Devise SessionController, Devise Custom Failure, debugging through, etc.., I finally found out what was going on and I decided to share the solution so you guys won't have to go through that.

The error 'Completed 401 Unauthorized in XXms' happens within the create method of SessionController at the line:

```
resource =  build_resource(...)
```

And the resource cannot be built since the resource is not passed to the server. Now the problem resides in WHY the resource isn't passed to the server? I'm using JQUERY mobile which post the sign_in as an AJAX call, which JQUERY cannot upload data like that through AJAX.

You need to add to your signin form the data-ajax=false:
in Devise/sessions/new.html.erb modify the form to look like this:

```
form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_url, html: {data: {ajax: false}}) do |f|
```

Hope that helps someone down the road.

Comment: Yohann T. Was this problem related to cancan, devise or both? Can you tell me more about the problem you were having, I might be having the same one